# Pass argument by reference TCL procedure

Tags: function, reference, parameter-passing, tcl, procedure

How to pass an argument by reference in the TCL procedure?

Look the following block of code:

```
proc test{&a} {
  set a 7
}

set b 5
test b
puts $b
```

I waited that the output should be 7, but it was 5.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Check out the `upvar` command.

Comment: That code didn't give you an error? *wrong # args: should be "proc name args body"* You need a space between the proc name and argument list.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use the `upvar` command to map the variable with that name in the caller's scope into the procedure's internal scope.

```
proc test {&a} {
    # It's a good idea to use an explicit level of 1
    upvar 1 ${&a} a
    set a 7
}
```

I'd not normally name a variable `&a`, as they're annoying to use with `$` syntax. I mostly prefer to use something like `varName` so that when someone reads the wrong-arguments error for `test` they get this readable version:

```
wrong # args: should be "test varName"
```